# New to C; using arrays. Undesirable output

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C (programming in general). I was working on this for a while, my school assignment. I'm getting an output of many random numbers (e.g. 1xxxxxxxxx) instead of printed displays of input entered.

Here's the code in question:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char item[5][20];
    double ppu[5], total, price[5], quantity[5];
    int i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter item, price and quantity: ");
        scanf("%s %f %f", &item[i], &ppu[i], &quantity[i]);

        price[i] = ppu[i]*quantity[i];
        total += price[i];
    }

printf("ITEM\t\tPRICE PER UNIT\t\tQUANTITY\t\tPRICE\n");
for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("%s\t\t%.2f\t\t%.0f\t\t%.2f\n", item[i], ppu[i], quantity[i], price[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't fix the output.

Comment: Please, provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - edit your post and add example of an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the format specifier to `%lf`. Don't forget to assign `total` with an initial value.

Comment: Thanks, changing it from %f to %lf worked. Is %lf the definitive specifier for double. while %f can be used for both float and double?

Comment: `scanf` is stricter than `printf`: `"%lf"` for double in scanf; `"%f"` for float in scanf; printf accepts (since C99) both "`%f`" and `"%lf"` for float (which is converted to double) and double. Oh! BTW, `"%Lf"` is used for `long double`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: To expand on @pmg's comment: for each format specifier `scanf` takes a pointer-to-*type* argument, and these are passed precisely as-is to variadic functions; `printf` takes a *type* argument, and `float` arguments are promoted to `double` in the call - `printf` can't tell if you passed a `float` or a `double` so it must treat both the same.

Answer (score 1):

`total` hasn't been assigned (or initialized with) a relevant value.

Also, `item[i]` (a pointer to 20 chars) is converted to a pointer to char (what `scanf` expects) in the context of `scanf`. The `&` is wrong

```
scanf("%s %f %f", &item[i], &ppu[i], &quantity[i]);
// wrong  ^^ ^^   ^
scanf("%s %lf %lf", item[i], &ppu[i], &quantity[i]); // thanks to Bpaul
```

Even better is making sure `scanf` did the right thing:

```
if (scanf("%s%lf%lf", item[i], &ppu[i], &quantity[i]) != 3) /* error */;
```

Comment: You may have heard the expression "in most contexts, arrays decay to pointers to their first element". I personally don't like that expression, preferring saying "arrays are converted to a pointer to their first element". Anyway, you might like to read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Try to put this in your code: printf("%p\n%p\n", item[0], item[1]); Examine the output.

Comment: I see that the values printed out seem to be addresses... maybe?

Comment: Yes, addresses in hex. What is the numerical difference between the 2? (Remember: hex!) Compare that to your item[][] dimension sizes (decimal!) You need to read up on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

None of these variables and array members are initialized.

```
char item[5][20];
double ppu[5], total, price[5], quantity[5];
int i;
```

That means that they will contain random garbage values.
Now, the ones that you assign to with either scanf or the assignment operator will contain (possibly) useful data, but you are also missing out checking the return value of scanf, which will tell you how many values could be successfully read.

Also look at the way you use the 2-D array item. There is something wrong there.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being silly or oblivious, but what's wrong with how I use the 2d array?

Comment: If you only needed one item, you would just use char item[20]. So that gives you an array of 20 chars. But what is the 1st dimension in your 2-D array? Multidimensional C arrays are arrays of arrays.

Comment: I want to have 5 strings up to 20 characters each with the array in question. Just learnt it in class so perhaps I've mixed something up.